# Audio Tag not working in HTML in Android

Tags: android, html5-audio

I have below test html used in android inapp webview

**Test Environment :** *Tablet with android version 4.1*

**Only 4th approach works with website url**

**1,2 and 3 doesn't work**, they show play button but once clicked it directly moves to end.

Also placed test image to check if path is correct and image is loaded.

Please check if i am doing anything wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


        1(relative Path). <audio controls="controls"> <source
            src="clima_Audio_1528708600.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        Audio not supported </audio><br/><br/><br/>

        2(absolute path). <audio controls="controls"> <source
            src="file:///sdcard/testapp//clima_Audio_1528708600.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        Audio not supported </audio><br/><br/><br/>

        3(absolute path). <audio controls="controls"> <source
            src="file:///sdcard/testapp//horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        Audio not supported </audio><br/><br/><br/>

        4(web url). <audio controls="controls"> <source
            src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        Audio not supported </audio><br/>

    <img src="file:///sdcard/testapp/test.png"/>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you browsing a website or are you in a webapp (phonegap app)?

Comment: I am using webview to open this html inapp

Answer (score 0):

1 (relative path)

From my experience, I have been only able to use a full local path, with a song embedded in the app :

```
<audio controls="controls">
    <source src="/android_asset/www/clima_Audio_1528708600.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
            Audio not supported 
</audio>
```

Where "android_assets" is your "assets" folder (yes, it tricky but it works)

2 (absolute path)

You cannot access directly a file located on the sd card directly from a WebView. I recommend to read a post about it on the [Tourizo Blog](http://blog.tourizo.com/2009/02/how-to-display-local-file-in-android.html).

3 (absolute path)

Same issue as 2.

Comment: My html file and audio file are both situated in sdcard

Comment: I am not sure that you can access to the sdcard directly from the webview. However, it is a bit weird to load your webview html page content from a sdcard.

Comment: Actually application structure is build that way, everything is coming from server audio as well as html file, hence its stored in sdcard, images are loaded, only problem is with audio files.